# Extract data from ServerRequest

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux

I am exploring Spring Boot with Kotlin and I found a really interesting way to define REST API using Functional endpoints.

It works just fine when I am dealing with JSON as a payload. In that case, I can easily get the body using `val body = serverRequest.awaitBody<CreateIncidentRequest>()`
However, I am trying to create an endpoint for uploading images alongside some data. I am aware that I can get data  `val multipartData = serverRequest.awaitMultipartData()` and then I can parse fields that I need. But I am wondering if is there a more convenient way to do this.

Using Java and regular blocking controller I can define an endpoint as

```java
@PostMapping("incidents")
public ResponseEntity<IncidentResponse> createIncident(
    @Valid @NotNull CreateIncidentRequest request, 
    @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image) throws IOException {
        Incident incident = incidentService.createIncident(request, image.getBytes());
        return ResponseEntity.created(URI.create("/api/v1/incidents/" + incident.getId())).build();
    }
```

Is there a way to get both *CreateIncidentRequest* and MultipartFile from ServerRequest if I am calling the endpoint as following

```bash
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/incidents' \
--form 'description="This is my first incident"' \
--form 'longitude="44.7547300"' \
--form 'latitude="17.1916924"' \
--form 'typeId="1f00eabe-0c54-4efe-ab6f-a4d1f78f9951"' \
--form 'image=@"/path/to/image.jpg"'
```

I am able to extract all fields by hand and then construct *CreateIncidentRequest* like this

```java
    @Bean
    fun httpIncidents(incidentService: IncidentService) = coRouter {
        "api/v1/".nest {
            POST("/incidents", accept(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)) { serverRequest ->
                val multipartData = serverRequest.awaitMultipartData()
                val description = (multipartData.getFirst("description") as FormFieldPart).value()
                val typeId = UUID.fromString((multipartData.getFirst("typeId") as FormFieldPart).value())
                val longitude = (multipartData.getFirst("longitude") as FormFieldPart).value().toDouble()
                val latitude = (multipartData.getFirst("latitude") as FormFieldPart).value().toDouble()
                val image = (multipartData.getFirst("image") as FormFieldPart).content().awaitSingle().asInputStream().readAllBytes()

                val request = CreateIncidentRequest(description, longitude, latitude, typeId)

                val incident = incidentService.createIncident(request, image)

                ServerResponse.created(URI.create("/api/v1/incidents/${incident.id}")).buildAndAwait()
            }
        }

    }
```

I tried like this but no luck. I get `415` as error

```java
    @Bean
    fun httpIncidents(incidentService: IncidentService) = coRouter {
        POST("api/v1/incidents", accept(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)) { serverRequest ->
            val request = serverRequest.awaitBody<CreateIncidentRequest>()
            val image = serverRequest.awaitMultipartData() // and then extract Multipart file for "image"

            val incident = incidentService.createIncident(request, image)

            ServerResponse.created(URI.create("/api/v1/incidents/${incident.id}")).buildAndAwait()
        }
    }
```

Comment: That same controller should work in webflux as well.

Comment: Sure, I just wondered if there is elegant way to do this using functional endpoints